# How to wait for one jquery animation to finish before the next one begins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, callback, sequential

I have the following jQuery:

```
$("#div1").animate({ width: '160' }, 200).animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 300 );
$("#div2").animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 300).animate({ width: '150' }, 200);
```

My issue is that both happen at the same time.  I would like the div2 animation to start when the first one finishes.  I've tried the method below, but it does the same thing:

```
$("#div1").animate({ width: '160' }, 200).animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 300, ShowDiv() );
....
function ShowDiv(){
   $("#div2").animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 300).animate({ width: '150' }, 200);
}
```

How can I make it wait for the first one to finish?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

animate has a "complete" function.  You should place the 2nd animation in the complete function of the first.

EDIT: example http://jsfiddle.net/xgJns/

```
$("#div1").animate({opacity:.1},1000,function(){
    $("#div2").animate({opacity:.1},1000);    
});​
```

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing in my second example?

Comment: Your 2nd example is close actually.  Remove the `()` from the `ShowDiv` in the first line.  You are calling the function rather than passing it.

Comment: gah! Thanks!  How would I pass it a parameter if I needed to?

Comment: simply remove the `()` and it works, functions can be passed around like any other variable, just don't add `()` which will call the function instead and pass the return value.

Comment: What I was asking, is if it is possible to pass a Parameter to ShowDiv

Comment: oh, yes, you would just have to wrap it in a function so `function(){ShowDiv('something')}` would be the third parameter to animage.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $("#div1").animate({ width: '200' }, 2000).animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 3000, function(){
    $("#div2").animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 3000).animate({ width: '150' }, 2000);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/joaquinrivero/TWA24/2/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function as parameter to the [`animate(..)`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function which is called after the animation completes. Like so:

```
$('#div1').animate({
    width: 160
}, 200, function() {
    // Handle completion of this animation
});
```

The example below is a clearer explanation of the parameters.

```
var options = { },
    duration = 200,
    handler = function() {
        alert('Done animating');
    };

$('#id-of-element').animate(options, duration, handler);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a timeout, use the complete callback.

```
$("#div1").animate({ width: '160' }, 200).animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 300, function(){

  $("#div2").animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 300).animate({ width: '150' }, 200);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Following what kingjiv said, you should use the `complete` callback to chain these animations. You almost have it in your second example, except you're executing your ShowDiv callback immediately by following it with parentheses. Set it to `ShowDiv` instead of `ShowDiv()` and it should work.

mcgrailm's response (posted as I was writing this) is effectively the same thing, only using an anonymous function for the callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#div1").animate({ width: '160' }, 200).animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 300, function () {
$("#div2").animate({ width: 'toggle' }, 300).animate({ width: '150' }, 200); });
```

This works for me. I'm not sure why your original code doesn't work. Maybe it needs to be incased in an anonymous function?