# Fade in and out using fadeToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fade

I'm using fadeToggle to fade a couple of images in and out on a loop. Is there a way to start the fading in of image 2 after image 1 is done fading out and so on?

This is the code I'm working with;

```
$(function() {
    function run_animation($element, delay, duration) {
        $element.delay(delay).fadeToggle(duration, function () {
            run_animation($element, delay, duration);
        });
    }
    run_animation($('.pointer1'), 1000, 1200);
    run_animation($('.pointer2'), 3000, 1200);
    run_animation($('.pointer3'), 4500, 1200);
    run_animation($('.pointer4'), 6000, 1200);
    run_animation($('.pointer6'), 7500, 1200);
    run_animation($('.pointer7'), 9000, 1200);
    run_animation($('.pointer8'), 10500, 1200);
});
```

Comment: Perhaps this thread could help out?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116597/how-to-wait-for-one-jquery-animation-to-finish-before-the-next-one-begins

Comment: perhaps add `$element.next()` in the recursive call? That is if the `img`s are siblings.

Comment: Can you maybe show me where to use that in my code? I'm very new to this. :P

Comment: Or something like this http://jsfiddle.net/AMRe7/

Comment: dfsq, that was perfect! Thanks!