# Prevent mousewheel when animation starts

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to **stop** mousewheel on the whole body, after an animation starts **on wheel**?

Like this:

```
body.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  // ...then do the animation here
}
```

Comment: Might [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47675009/11135261) be of help to you?

Comment: Will try it now @GogoDev

Comment: Good for you @Hejha